# Parsing icalendar datetime YYYYMMDDTHHMMSSZ with moment.js

Tags: javascript, icalendar, momentjs

I'm trying to parse the YYYYMMDDTHHMMSSZ format with moment.js, but I always get "Invalide date".

Is there a way to parse it?

Answer (score 6):

`moment` takes a second parameter that indicates the format, so you can do:

```
var dtg = '20140112T121537Z';
moment(dtg, 'YYYYMMDDTHHmmssZ');
```

Comment: [Moment's formatting tokens](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string-format/) are case sensitive.  I updated your answer accordingly.